# Accuracy of the Mathew Hansen Dataset?

Tags: remote-sensing

Can anyone cast light on the accuracy assessment of the [Mathew Hansen dataset](https://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest)?

What will be the proper way of using this data for research?

I am asking this since I know that any of the remote sensing classification work without ground truthing/accuracy assessment is useless - is my understanding correct?

I do not find anything on the accuracy assessment of this data on the internet. Even not the methodology for this data though a bit very uncomplete discussion at [Methodology for Hansen classification of Global Forest Watch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129899)

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual article referenced in your last link doesn't contain any information about error or accuracy.  However, in the fine print, there is a link to supplemental materials and methods.  You can download the [**pdf here**](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2013/11/14/342.6160.850.DC1/Hansen.SM.pdf).

I didn't read the whole article, but the first search on "error" yielded this paragraph:

> Estimated error matrices and accuracy summary statistics are shown in
>   Tab. S5. For loss, user’s and producer’s accuracies are balanced and
>   greater than 80% per climate domain and the globe as a whole. Results
>   for forest gain indicate a possible underestimate of tropical forest
>   gain with a user’s accuracy of 82% and a producer’s accuracy of 48%.
>   However, the 95% confidence interval for the bias of tropical forest
>   gain (expressed as a % of land area) is 0.01% to 0.35%, indicating
>   high uncertainty in the validation estimate. A possible overestimate
>   of boreal forest gain is also indicated. Overall, the comparison of
>   individually interpreted sample sites with the algorithm output
>   illustrates a robust product at the 120m pixel scale.

Page 16 contains Table S5, which lists Accuracy assessment of 2000 to 2012 forest loss and gain at global and climate domain scales.

[image]

There are similar tables for Tropical, Subtropical, Temperate, and Boreal Climate domains on pages 16-20.

Comment: @Fetzer Great! any hope for 2001-2014 data?

Comment: I don't know.  I'd ask that as a new question.